# Deploy SWT applications for multiple platforms

Tags: java, deployment, swt, multiplatform

We plan to add all swt.jar files to the `Class-Path` entry of the main application's MANIFEST file and only ship the platform-specific swt.jar in the platform-specific bundle. This most likely will require different bundles for, e.g., Windows 32-bit, Windows 64-bit, GTK-Linux, and so on. Generic bundles which can work on all platforms are not possible without the user having to move files around or delete not required ones.

Another idea could be to deliver all swt.jar files and dynamically loading the right one.

What suggestion do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You could create different launchers which set the classpath for each platform.

When you plan to use java webstart you can specify the jars for different platforms using the resources element in the jnlp:

`<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">`

`<nativelib href="swt-windows-32-3.6.jar" />`

`</resources>`

If you want to get Mac Os X users you should think about to create a .app bundle inside a dmg.